# Mounting an elastic file system to AWS Batch Computer Enviroment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I'm trying to get my elastic file system (EFS) to be mounted in my docker container so it can be used with AWS batch. Here is what I did:

1. Create a new AMI that is optimized for Elastic Container Services (ECS). I followed [this guide here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-batch-ami.html) to make sure it had ECS on it. I also put the mount into `/etc/fstab` file and verified that my EFS was being mounted (/mnt/efs) after reboot.
2. Tested an EC2 instance with my new AMI and verified I could pull the docker container and pass it my mount point via

`docker run --volume /mnt/efs:/home/efs -it mycontainer:latest`

Interactively running the docker image shows me my data inside efs

3. [Set up a new compute enviorment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environments.html) with my new AMI that mounts EFS on boot.
4. Create a JOB definition File:

   ```
   {
   "jobDefinitionName": "MyJobDEF",
   "jobDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:batch:us-west-2:#######:job-definition/Submit:8",
   "revision": 8,
   "status": "ACTIVE",
   "type": "container",
   "parameters": {},
   "retryStrategy": {
       "attempts": 1
   },
   "containerProperties": {
       "image": "########.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mycontainer",
       "vcpus": 1,
       "memory": 100,
       "command": [
           "ls",
           "/home/efs",
       ],
       "volumes": [
           {
               "host": {
                   "sourcePath": "/mnt/efs"
               },
               "name": "EFS"
           }
       ],
       "environment": [],
       "mountPoints": [
           {
               "containerPath": "/home/efs",
               "readOnly": false,
               "sourceVolume": "EFS"
           }
       ],
       "ulimits": []
   }
   ```

   }
5. Run Job, view log

Anyway, while it does not say "no file /home/efs found" it does not list anything in my EFS which is populated, which I'm inerpreting as the container mounting an empty efs. What am I doing wrong? Is my AMI not mounting the EFS in the compute environment?

Answer (score -2):

I covered this in a recent blog post

https://medium.com/arupcitymodelling/lab-note-002-efs-as-a-persistence-layer-for-aws-batch-fcc3d3aabe90

You need to set up a launch template for your batch instances, and you need to make sure that your subnets/security groups are configured properly.

Comment: Welcome, Sean, and thanks for deciding to contribute. Would it be possible to flesh this answer out a little, so that if the third-party link rots away, what remains stands as its own answer?